# 555 timer blink circuit not working

Tags: 555

I received my 555 timers in the mail today, and I wanted to make a simple blinking circuit, but no matter what I do, the LED just stays on, it does not flash.

Even stranger is that this exact circuit works in Tinkercad but not on my breadboard. I would appreciate it if anyone could point out what is wrong here.

Here is my circuit in Tinkercad and real life. The resistor from pin 8-7 is 1 kΩ and from 7-6 is 100 kΩ, the capacitor is 10 µF.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An assembly photo and a simulated assembly photo, neither of which have power and GND connections indicated, do not tell us what we need to know.  Please post the exact schematic you are building to.  Be sure to include a unique reference designator for each component, so we can discuss them without ambiguity.

Comment: A common beginner mistake is to omit decoupling capacitors. Put one 33 uF or larger from power to ground somewhere on the breadboard. Put a 0.1 ceramic directly from pin 8 to pin 4 of the 555.

Comment: What is your supply voltage? It looks like TinkerCad is throwing an "!" warning over the LED. If you are using a 5 V (or higher) supply and that is truly a 47 ohm resistor in series with the LED then you are sending way too much current through the LED (about 70mA). Use a 470 ohm instead. However, might you be using 5-banded 1% resistors? If so, recheck all your values. if still unsure use a DVM-Ohm meter for verification. If you still require help providing a standard schematic drawing would be best. (The forum includes a schematic app, see the small circuit icon.)

Comment: I believe a 0.1uF cap on pin 5 is recommended for stability.

Comment: a little embarrassing, i had my power supply on the wrong direction 5V- into the 5V+ slot and vice versa. happened just now when I checked it so I could give you guys the volts I was using, so thanks for that. so it's working now, sorry for the inconvenience